# How to sort an array class by name property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have an array of Relation class on ruby on rails which I call using `@relations`

Example:

```
@relations[0] {id => 13, name => 'Giovanni', age => 50}
@relations[1] {id => 25, name => 'Astolf', age => 27}
@relations[2] {id => 5, name => 'Bob', age => 37}
```

I want to sort this array based on name. It'll as listed below:

```
@relations[0] {id => 25, name => 'Astolf', age => 27}
@relations[1] {id => 5, name => 'Bob', age => 37}
@relations[2] {id => 13, name => 'Giovanni', age => 50}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

very simple:

```
@relations = [{:id => 13, :name => 'Giovanni', :age => 50},
              {:id => 25, :name => 'Astolf', :age => 27},
              {:id => 5, :name => 'Bob', :age => 37}]

@relations.sort_by{|e| e[:name]}
# => [{:id=>25, :name=>"Astolf", :age=>27},
#     {:id=>5, :name=>"Bob", :age=>37},
#     {:id=>13, :name=>"Giovanni", :age=>50}]
```

Comment: Alright, this is really correct. But if name was got by a another function? Example: @relations[0].getname => "Astolf"?

Comment: I found on this site: http://ariejan.net/2007/01/28/ruby-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-an-attribute/. Thanks.